# Excel formula to get first non-empty value and then return value other row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

This formula:

`=INDEX(Q10:XFD10,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((Q10:XFD10<>0),0),0))`

looks up the first non-zero value from column `Q` till the end in row `10`.

And it displays the value present in that cell. Suppose the cell found is `V10`.
I must display the value in cell `V7`.

I cannot change the range to lookup the first non-empty cell, because the higher rows are always filled.

There probably are two possible answers
One answer that looks up 3 rows higher (10-7=3) and another answer that looks up in the fixed row `V$7`.

I need the last option.

Comment: I think you mean XFD77?  In any case, you should be able to use [OFFSET()](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/offset.html) to return the value of the cell three rows before the cell found by the MATCH(().

Comment: Or you could just do this: `=INDEX(Q10:XFD10,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((Q10:XFD10<>0),0),0)-3)`

Comment: `OFFSET` works, other suggestion fails. Using 3 - `ROW()` I get an offset that copies to other rows. All right, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose the cell found is V10.
>    I must display the value in cell V7.

Then I'll propose a simple " if (row 10 is not zero ) & if( sum(from the left) = 0 ) " test will do, (assuming cell P10 is empty).

in Q7, put `=IF(AND(Q10<>0,SUM($P$10:P10)=0),Q10,"")`